# React issue with product listing in the cart section

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue with the cart section of my react project. The issue is when I try to add items with different options it acts like I just changed the quantity and it goes with the same options of the first selection.

here is the code of the additem function.

```
function addItem(state, product, options, quantity) {
    const itemIndex = findItemIndex(state.items, product, options);

    let newItems;
    let { lastItemId } = state;

    if (itemIndex === -1) {
        lastItemId += 1;
        newItems = [...state.items, {
            id: lastItemId,
            product: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product)),
            options: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(options)),
            price: product.price,
            total: product.price * quantity,
            quantity,
        }];
    } else {
        const item = state.items[itemIndex];

        newItems = [
            ...state.items.slice(0, itemIndex),
            {
                ...item,
                quantity: item.quantity + quantity,
                total: (item.quantity + quantity) * item.price,
            },
            ...state.items.slice(itemIndex + 1),
        ];
    }
    const subtotal = calcSubtotal(newItems);
    const total = calcTotal(subtotal, state.extraLines);

    return {
        ...state,
        lastItemId,
        subtotal,
        total,
        items: newItems,
        quantity: calcQuantity(newItems),
    };
}
```

as requested here we go,

```
function findItemIndex(items, product, options) {
    return items.findIndex((item) => {
        if (item.product.id !== product.id || item.options.length !== options.length) {
            return false;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i += 1) {
            const option = options[i];
            const itemOption = item.options.find((itemOption) => (
                itemOption.optionId === option.optionId && itemOption.valueId === option.valueId
            ));

            if (!itemOption) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: This function uses the `findItemIndex` function to determine whether a matching item already exists. Your issue is that you're expecting different options to give you back an index of -1, but its in fact giving you back the index of an existing item in the cart. The bug is likely inside that function, which you haven't included in this question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @StephenJennings as you requested I added the function.

Comment: oh yes found the bug thank you so much @StephenJennings. The thing was there was no valueID inside products.options so I changed it and it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear. It would be nice if you would add your discovery as an answer to this question and accept it, so SO users know this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem the bug causes of there was no option named valueID. since it doesn't throw errors it's not found option and listing products as the same product.

here is the solution.

```
function findItemIndex(items, product, options) {
    return items.findIndex((item) => {
        if (item.product.id !== product.id || item.options.length !== options.length) {
            return false;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i += 1) {
            const option = options[i];
            const itemOption = item.options.find((itemOption) => (
                // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
                itemOption.optionId === option.optionId && itemOption.optionColorValue === option.optionColorValue && itemOption.optionSizeValue === option.optionSizeValue
            ));
            if (!itemOption) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    });
}
```